# ZF2 - Lightweight onbootstrap() for common sql

Tags: zend-framework2

I have a website made in ZF2 that contain a menu filled with sql, and another things that is also filled in that way, and these parts repeat in every page of the website. All this sql are placed in the onBootstrap() method, and I know that is not a good pratice, but in that way I don't have to repeat these sql in every action. My question is: how can I clean my onBotstrap() method without have to repeat these query in every action?

Thanks for help.

Comment: This question is easily answerable at google. Their are lot of blogs/tutorials for build dynamic navigation. Still you can found solution around Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory

Comment: For other part you should build services and call them at onBootstrap dispatch event.

Comment: Thanks for answer. In the case of navigation, it's already working, I don't need to create it. I think the dispach will solve the problem, but I wanna call an event just in some actions, not in every. Is there some way to do it?

Comment: Sounds like you're in need of a navigation container factory, and possibly some view helpers. Post some of the code if you can.